# how to install libGL files

Tags: command-line, steam

I was just wondering what command I would use in front or behind a file name to install (I am very new to Linux and nothing seems to work for me, not even steam).

Answer (score 8):

Most probably you'll want `apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx`. Found that by `apt-cache search libgl |egrep '^libgl[^a-z]'`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Docker, you probably want to install `libgl1-mesa-glx`. Here, an example for a `node` container.

```
FROM node:10.0.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Comment: this is the same as my answer :(

Comment: Using your solution in a `Dockerfile` wont work. Therefore your solution is not targetting Docker users. Whereas mine is. Hence there are two different answers. The only similarities here is the package used of course, but this is not what it makes it the same answer. We are here to help people, not chasing points and fame don't forget that.

Answer (score 6):

There are many tools to install packages in Ubuntu, some of these tools are GUI (such as Ubuntu Software Center - Synaptic - etc ...) while others still CLI if you like the command line mode(such as `apt-get` , `dpkg` , `aptitude` ...).

The most known command to install a package is

```
sudo apt-get install package-name
```

So all of what you want to do is to insert the correct package name.

So for your question you can run;

```
sudo apt-get install libgl
```

But this would produce an error

```
E: Unable to locate package libgl
```

why? because the package name is not correct. A nice trick in Linux terminal is to use double <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete so while writing the command above do the trick. the output would be like:

```
$sudo apt-get install libgl
```

hit double <kbd>Tab</kbd> output will be

```
Display all 272 possibilities? (y or n)
```

This means you have 272 possible packages starting with name libgl,

so you have to know exactly what you want to install.

This is just a start to know more about software installation in Ubuntu you probably have to read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware and also this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter would be helpful

Answer (score 6):

The file `libGL.so` is in various different packages. Depending on your graphic card choose [one of them](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so):

**package-name:**

```
fglrx
fglrx-updates
nvidia-173
nvidia-304-updates
nvidia-304
nvidia-331-updates
```

Install them with:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

Comment: thanks everyone, but I'm moving to Windows...

Comment: and which one do i choose? whatever i like? . edit actually, there is a package called `nvidia-latest`